# Memory Leakage Handling in Desktop Application C#

Tags: c#, .net

How could I find memory leakage in my C# Desktop Application?

Is there any 3rd party tool which could notify me where the memory leakage is happening.

There are lots of tools available on net, but for web applications, I need the one which could find memory leakage in desktop application.

Comment: Which version of Visual Studio are you using?  VS2012 comes with a pretty rich set of [analysis tools](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182372.aspx)...

Comment: @chappoo Question is about **How could I find memory leakage**. Vs tool is for performance

Comment: @SriramSakthivel [this may help](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd264934.aspx)

Answer (score 2):

Try using `ANTS Profiler`. Its main use is to is to find memory leaks. It can be used for desktop applications, .NET web applications and services, Serviced Components hosted in COM+, and Windows Services

**Update:**

Please refer [ANTS Memory Profiler 7](http://www.red-gate.com/products/dotnet-development/ants-memory-profiler/video/) Link.
It has some demonstration videos for beginners. It will definitely help you.

Comment: Is there also any open source / no license cost SW ?

Comment: thanks for your reply.. Kindly could you tell me how to use it. do i need to give it my .exe file or entire project and how it would notify me by log or by taking me to a particular part of code?

Comment: Please see my updates